# How to set limit while fetching data using $getjson()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching news articles from a site using `$getjson()` method. currently I am getting all articles but I want that only 10 articles should be returned in call. Is it possible to limit the response while fetching data using getjson method? If yes please show me how can I do it.

Here is my code sample:

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
      $.each(data['news'], function(i, article){
        $('#news').append('<h2>' + article['title'] + '</h2><p>' + article['content'] + '</p>');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Depends on configuration of api . There is no generic solution for how remote server determines what to send. Read the api docs