# Get fixed number of JSON objects from third-party API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working with this returned API from a third party:

(note: returns LARGE dataset)

https://www.saferproducts.gov/RestWebServices/Recall?format=json

I know I can get this giant object like so:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.saferproducts.gov/RestWebServices/Recall?format=json', function(json, textStatus) {
        console.log(json);
});
```

This returns ~7000 objects. There is no way in the API call to dictate how many objects you want returned. It's all or nothing.

Here's the question...can I use `getJSON` (or similar) to only get the first 5 objects and stop without having to load the entire JSON file first?

Comment: If the service does not provide a way of reducing the number of objects, then no, there's no way of not loading the entire file. The best you could do is to load the file as text, then use some string manipulation to get the objects you want. But that could very well take just as much time as parsing the JSON, and would be more error-prone.

Comment: No.  It returns what it returns, and you can only modify it or use it *after* that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589289/how-to-set-limit-while-fetching-data-using-getjson?

Comment: Do you have a web server you could use to periodically download the JSON and then query it from there instead?  That way you could filter it in any way you wish.

Comment: Okay...then what's the best way to know for sure when the object is completely returned and do I have to wait to start iterating through it until it's full loaded?

Comment: @archer That's a decent solution.

Comment: Not perfect, but probably the best you'll get unless they offer some parameters with the call.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while a go.  I used PHP to fetch a webpage of an api.  Then I would cache it.  Via PHP logic, I stored a variable inside a text file which contained all the information from the webpage.  I had another file that stored the timestamp.  Then, when the page was called, php would check the timestamp to see how old it was.  If it was too old, it'd recache the page and return relevant information.  If it was still valid, it would just return the cached information.  If you only want the last 5, the PHP logic wouldn't be too hard to write that in.  Then, jQuery would query the PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have anything called out in their documentation for limiting the returns. I think their intent is for you to narrow down your search so you're not fetching every single item. You could always email them and ask as what Mike McCaughan said, if they don't have a 'limit' baked in, then no, it's not possible.

It also looks like they offer weekly downloads that you can just create your own API and add a limit property:

https://www.fda.gov/%20Safety/Recalls/EnforcementReports/default.htm

Reference:

- https://github.com/presidential-innovation-fellows/recalls-api/wiki/data-sources
- https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/CPSC-Recalls-Application-Program-Interface-API-Information/
- https://www.cpsc.gov/Global/info/Recall/CPSC-Recalls-Retrieval-Web-Services-Programmers-Guide_3-25-2015.pdf

If there really is no option for limiting that call, then I'd suggest caching, showing some kind of processing wheel while the call takes place or narrowing your query. They have options to for filtering that may work for you such as the following:

```
RecallNumber
RecallDateStart
RecallDateEnd
LastPublishDateStart
LastPublishDateEnd
RecallURL
RecallTitle
ConsumerContact
RecallDescription
ProductName
ProductDescription
ProductModel
ProductType
RecallInconjunctionCountry
ImageURL
Injury
ManufacturerCountry
UPC – see caveat below
Hazard
Manufacturer
Remedy
Retailer
```